# 2 drop down list and calendar to display gridview in C#

Tags: c#

I have simple booking ticketing system for my school project and am using windows form in asp.net. i have simple search where the person can input bickup, drop off and date. am using drop down list FOR bickup and dropoff and date normal calendar attached to text box. but i can't populate the gridview e.g bus rides available from one position to another in specific dates , like from A to B in 24 of August. my date i stored as date others Nvarchar. i can bind the drop down list but the search button shows nothing.
below is my front code and back-end code. please i need help am new to c# and coding in general.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbdates" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BusNo" HeaderText="Bus Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Bickup" HeaderText="Bick Up" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DropOff" HeaderText="Drop Off" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fare" HeaderText="Fare" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#33CCFF" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <br />
    </form>


public partial class DriverDisplay : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fill_DropDownList1();
                fill_DropDownList2();
            }

        }
        private void fill_DropDownList1()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Ticket";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con2);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Bickup";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Bickup";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        private void fill_DropDownList2()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Ticket";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Dropoff";
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "DropOff";
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;


        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbdates.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tbdates.Text);
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ToString());

            sqlcon.Open();

            string query = "select * from Ticket where date = @Date";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            SqlParameter date = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            sqlcon.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should i know what my value is please i don't know am so sorry but am here to learn.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "select * from Ticket where date = @Date";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Date", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["Date"].Value = "you date value";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Thank you so much i will try and let you know. my Date value would be what as am using calendar with textbox. should it be tbdate as ID of the texbox.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: The problem is with the date.  The database has the date stored with hour, minutes, and seconds so you never matches.  So use "select * from Ticket where Day(date) = @Date"

Comment: @jdweng its stored as date DD/MM/YYYY. in my database. thanks i will try as well still am fixing it. Taw i thought some pple will assume am using MVC OR  will be confuse what am using.

Comment: The date is store as a number so format DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY shouldn't make a difference.  TimeZone may make a difference becuase the Day could be off by 1.   So if you are trying to get days in a workweek and you ask for a Monday day it could be stored as Sunday.

Comment: I still can't fix it would you guys help me. nothing shows when i click search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few mistakes in your code, i recommend you to read about CRUD Operations using ADO.Net and C# in ASP.Net, how to use SqlConnection and SqlCommand types. When you work with asp.net web forms you can use SqlDataSource control to provide data for your controls.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbdates" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Bickup" DataValueField="Bickup">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="DropOff" DataValueField="Dropoff">
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BusNo" HeaderText="Bus Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Bickup" HeaderText="Bick Up" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DropOff" HeaderText="Drop Off" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fare" HeaderText="Fare" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#33CCFF" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabase1ConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [BusNo], [date], [time], [Bickup], [DropOff], [Fare] FROM [Ticket]">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabase1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BusNo], [date], [time], [Bickup], [DropOff], [Fare] FROM [Ticket] WHERE ([date] = @date)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="date" DbType="Date" Name="date" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is yours DriverDisplay :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbdates.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["date"] == null)
            {
                Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("date"));
            }
            Request.Cookies["date"].Value = tbdates.Text;
        }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. For sure i will learn those one you recommended. I still was not able until you came along i tried so many times but i completely fail. Am student and i spent so much time just to figure out this. thanks again.